# customizing tab control in stylesheet in qt

Tags: qt, tabs, stylesheet

I would like to do changes only for a specific tab. How can I do it?

I tried both:

```
QTabBar::tab#tbGeneral{... } 

QTabWidget::tab-bar#tbGeneral{... }
```

None worked.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use the stylesheet or can you do it in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have probably looked into [Customizing QTabWidget and QTabBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar).

To style individual tabs based on their state (:only-one, :first, :last, :middle, :previous-selected, :next-selected, :selected) you can use stylesheet-code similar to this:

```
QTabBar::tab {
    border: 1px solid #C4C4C3;
    border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background-color: #f14040;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

As the individual tabs are not widgets (or objects), they have no object name or other properties that could identify them to a stylsheet. You can only use the pseudo-classes to style tabs with a stylesheet.

You'll probably have to use (C++) code to change the style of a tab depending on the label. The recommended way for customizing styles in Qt is through the class [`QStyle`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstyle.html#creating-a-custom-style). You can either subclass `QStyle` or use `QProxyStyle` to change the looks of specific widgets. The other alternative (probably not recommended by Qt) is though subclassing QTabBar and reimplementing the function [`QWidget::paintEvent( QPaintEvent *event)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

Comment: you misunderstood me. i don't want to change the pane. i only want

Comment: to differ between two cases: if the first tab is selected or not. maybe i didnwt make myself clear before.